# How to pass info from inside of object inside a state

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxtjs and I would like to take an id that is in my state and use it to make a new call to an API.

My `carInfo` has an IdAddress that I would like to use to call the API.

My store:

```
    export const state = () => ({
      allCars: [],
      carInfo: [],
      carAddress: []
    });

    export const actions = {
      async fetchAll({ commit }) {
        let cars= await this.$axios.$get(
          "apiaddress"
        );
        commit("setCars", cars);
      },

      async fetchcar({ commit }, id) {
        let car= await this.$axios.$get(
            "apiaddress"
        );
        commit("setcar", car);
      },

      async fetchAddress({ commit }, id) {
        let address = await this.$axios.$get(
          "apiaddress"
        );
        commit("setAddress", address);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Actions documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#actions) says:

> Action handlers receive a context object which exposes the same set of
>   methods/properties on the store instance, so you can call `context.commit` to 
>   commit a mutation, or access the state and getters via `context.state` and 
>   `context.getters`.

And it goes on to say that they often use [argument destructuring](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#destructuring) which is why the parameter to actions often looks like this: `{ commit }`.

In your case you could add `state` to the parameters and then you should be able to access your `carInfo` value from the state.

For example, change your `fetchAll` action to:

```
async fetchAll({ commit, state }) {
  let cars = await this.$axios.$get(
    apistate.carInfo.IdAddress
  );
  commit("setCars", cars);
},
```

Comment: I need to take all cars for in push to array. After I took one car, and i would like to inside of this car object take an ID Address and call my api to take info abou this address.

Comment: @ZeusAC I don't understand your question. Is this a different question to your question above?